# How can I create an inline abstract class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, mixins

This is the error I'm facing:

```
src/Model.ts:11:16 - error TS2797: A mixin class that extends from a type variable containing an abstract construct signature must also be declared 'abstract'.

11   return class Foo2 extends Base {
                  ~~~~
```

and this is the code:

```js
abstract class ModelBase {
  bar() {
    console.log("bar")
  }
}

type GConstructor<T = {}> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
type Foo = GConstructor<ModelBase>

function Foo2<TBase extends Foo>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Foo2 extends Base {
    foo() {
      console.log(this.bar())
    }
  }
}

export const Model = Foo2(ModelBase)
```

If I add `abstract` to the return statement, as in:

```js
  return abstract class Foo2 extends Base {
```

I get the error:

```
src/Model.ts:11:19 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

11   return abstract class Foo2 extends Base {
                     ~~~~~
```

So, how can I make this work? Essentially adding a mixin to an abstract class resulting in another abstract class.

Comment: You can't return an abstract class, because abstract classes are TypeScript and therefore do not exist at runtime.

Comment: I think this could be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe your requirement directly.

Comment: The main point of abstract class is that it is unconstructable directly

Comment: @captain-yossarian he doesn't want to instantiate it, he just wants to extend it while preserving the abstractness. Seems a legit requirement to me ‍♂️

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir sure, you are right, I did not read the question thoroughly. Your answer looks good!

Comment: @DeanXu I want to build an ORM modelled after ActiveRecord and I'm exploring which of the ActiveRecord techniques used to compose its building blocks can work in TypeScript.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a class declaration `abstract` is not supported on class expressions

```
abstract class ModelBase {
  bar() {
    console.log("bar")
  }
  abstract abstr(): void
}

type GConstructor<T = {}> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
type Foo = GConstructor<ModelBase>

export function Foo2<TBase extends Foo>(Base: TBase) {
  abstract class Foo2 extends Base {
    foo() {
      console.log(this.bar())
    }
  }
  return Foo2
}

export const Model = Foo2(ModelBase)

class X extends Model {
    abstr(): void {
    }
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgewCYFNkAhNfBAbwCgEERgoAKASgupqWwDsxtl8A6ZNgDmDAER0oYpmwC+bUJBjwEi6MwBcCAG7YAlrkrzKEAJ4AHMgHEAwlyUBXeNigAeACoIAvBVkA+b1VwaDhETnwAdwQGflj6YTAtYE5TAG0AXRYvAPcAbhMLMgAxbGxA23toJwgXVxwCYlI-Skp8AA9zF0QAMwdOeD0uBBLsACYPEjAydoh8TlwMEb8GSfwtd1WWKho1ZUQUNEXS0YQZuYWEVdZ2BG7S5mubjm5eASFRCAALPTB+SWYZDd5DRgQgoPgIA4oJxhscjC12p0oPtKlg8IRAiNRgx6oRNi0DugEAANU5tWbzDC45CPHbBRhMLS6Ay0hCgmiwSpQaouB7bJ40MAOSwM-JA+GUIA)

NOTE: I think you might have issues with declaration emit if you use this. The playground seems to generate some bad types for this (`Model: (abstract new (...args: any[]) /*...*/`). You might need to be more explicit with types if you use declaration emit.